# solve for n in the permutation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations

please help me im stuck and need help on this question.
I have tried the equation n!/ (n-1)! and i could not get the right answer. 
please i need help

this is the question:
 n+1P3=12(n-1P2)

Comment: The (*education*) tag is only meant to be used for questions about pedagogy and the *act* of educating.  It is not meant to be used simply because you are being educated and the question arose during the process of your learning.  Similarly this has nothing to do with statistics or data analysis.  Please confirm that the tags you use actually have *something* to do with your actual question before using them.

Answer (score 0):

On the left, you have (n+1)P(3) = $(n+1)(n)(n-1)$ and on the right, you have (n-1)P(2) = $(n-1)(n-2)$. Then you have the equation:

$$(n+1)(n)(n-1)=12(n-1)(n-2)$$

$$(n+1)n=12(n-2)$$

$$n^2+n=12n-24$$

$$n^2-11n+24=0$$

$$(n-8)(n-3)=0$$

We find the solutions $n=3$ and $n=8$.

Comment: Just fyi, when you cancel out a factor of a variable from both sides, that was a solution. So you actually just disregarded *n=1* from the cubic that you would've had if you'd expanded it. Though it's probably not a particularly meaningful solution to the original problem